# How is it possible to insert a system tray artifact in a secondary lxde-panel?

Tags: linux, lxde, panel

I need a second lxpanel to be shown on my second monitor, I've created one, but I'm not able to insert a `System Tray` artifact on it.

I suppose that `System Tray` is the panel-item that shows items such as: `nm-applet`, `bluetooth` and more that I'ld desire to see.

I don't find which item of the lxpanel menu (right mouse click on the panel) `Add/Remove Panel Items` is the `System Tray` item.

Comment: Huh... It looks like you're right. I never noticed that before and I use two separate panels. This doesn't help - but it eliminates it (probably). I tried adding it manually with editing the files in `.config/lxpanel/Lubuntu/panels.config/lxpanel/Lubuntu/panels` and restarting the panels, but it didn't work. So, that is one way you can eliminate from the list of things to try.

Comment: @KGIII , I tried also to copy the base/main panel file into the other (2nd) panel file modifing the monitor setting inside. But I've obtained similar but not identical panels ... On the 2nd monitor there's no `System Tray` ... Arg!